# What was the price of a theatre ticket in London during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, entertainment

I would like to know the price of a theatre ticket in the city of London during the second world war.
I can't find this information anywhere.

Comment: Presumably this is London, England (and not just the City of London)?

Comment: Check the London newspaper archives for WW2 for theatre advertisments. They will probably show a range of prices depending on the seating (stalls, balcony, boxes, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Answer (score 8):

***UK Pre-decimal Currency**: there were twenty shillings (s) to a pound and twelve pence (d) to a shilling. If written '7/6, this means 7 shillings and 6 pence.*

***Exchange rate**: [for most of the war, £1 = $4.03](http://www.miketodd.net/encyc/dollhist.htm) so 1 shilling was about 20 US cents.*

Prices varied enormously, depending on the theatre, the cast, and (especially) where you were seated. **A box for four or five cost several pounds while some stall seats and the balcony could be as little as 2s6d (2 shillings and six pence, about £5 in today's money)**. At least one theatre offered anumber free tickets to servicemen. Worth noting, though, is that few theatres in central London were open (especially at night) until the [London Blitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blitz) was over (May 1941).

---

The example below is for the [Q theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_Theatre), near Kew Bridge (Hounslow, London), in 1944.

[image]

[*Source*](https://picclick.co.uk/1944-Q-Theatre-Opposite-The-Bridge-Kew-John-353488488911.html#&gid=1&pid=3)

The programme also carried this message in case of an air raid warning during a performance:

[image]

Such notices were [found in all programmes](https://archives.history.ac.uk/history-in-focus/War/londonLeisure.html):

> The programmes always include instructions on what to do in the case
> of an air raid. Audiences were warned that an air raid was in progress
> through illuminated signs, and were free to leave for a shelter if
> they wished: ‘All we ask is that ‘ if you feel you must go you will
> depart quietly and without excitement’, as the programme for Olivier’s
> Richard III at the New Theatre put it in September 1944. Many
> theatregoers preferred to stay put and enjoy the play.

The [Windmill Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windmill_Theatre#%22We_Never_Closed%22:_World_War_II) remained open throughout the war (except for 12 days in Sept. 1939) with the [Windmill Girls](http://www.arthurlloyd.co.uk/Archive/Feb2003/Windmillgirls.htm) as the main attraction. **A special midnight matinee in 1940 cost 1 guinea** (1 pound and 1 shilling, or about $4.20 at the time); as this was for war relief, the ticket price was likely inflated. However, for a while (at least) the theatre was giving [500 free tickets a week](https://fyeahhistory.com/2019/01/08/the-windmill-the-show-girls-that-bolstered-the-blitz/) to soldiers.

[image]

*"Windmill Theatre Special Revudeville Show.2nd February,1940." [Text and Image source](https://www.flickriver.com/photos/40604141@N02/popular-interesting/).*

The [Stoll Theatre in Kingsway](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/184936355356?hash=item2b0f10d61c:g:KUUAAOSwLG5gMktn) (central London) had **prices ranging from 2s6d (balcony) to 10s6d** for a performance of *[Show Boat](https://ovrtur.com/production/2897316)* in 1943. The [London Palladium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Palladium) had an even greater range of prices as it also had boxes, though the example below is for a revue from just after the war ([1946](http://www.guidetomusicaltheatre.com/shows_h/hightime.htm)).

[image]

[Source](https://picclick.co.uk/1940s-High-Time-London-palladium-theatre-programme-203524550438.html#&gid=1&pid=2)

A little before the war (1937), the [Theatre Royal, Haymarket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatre_Royal_Haymarket) advertised the following prices for a performance of *[Juno and the Paycock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_and_the_Paycock)* by Sean O'Casey. Again, you can see that prices depend on location within in the theatre.

[image]

During the London Blitz especially, the [choice of performances was very limited](https://archives.history.ac.uk/history-in-focus/War/londonLeisure.html) due to the closure of theatres.

> Air raids disrupted performances. These problems were ventilated
> regularly and fully in trade journals like Theatre World which
> lamented in October 1940 that due to the Blitz ‘The choice of the
> Londoner is now restricted to the delights of the Revudeville at the
> Windmill and the lunch-time ballet hour at the Arts Theatre Club, to
> which must be added the brave venture of Shakespeare at the
> Vaudeville, matinées only’. Things got easier once the Blitz was over,
> but the flying bombs of 1944 brought another crisis, closing many
> shows...

Nonetheless,

> It rapidly became clear that the continuation of normal leisure
> facilities would be essential to maintain general morale and some
> sense of normality. Londoners and visitors alike needed some
> distraction from long working hours, CD commitments, travel problems
> and air raids, and theatre-going was a popular pastime.

[Productions in 1940 and 1941](https://archive.org/details/londonstagein20t0000tani/page/120/mode/2up?q=ticket) included such major stars as [John Gielgud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gielgud), [Robert Donat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Donat), [Alec Guinness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alec_Guinness), and [Michael Redgrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Redgrave). Also, [theatre productions could serve a useful propaganda purpose](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/new-theatre-quarterly/article/abs/theatre-in-britain-during-the-second-world-war/5BC40FE354DA569F4F6E07F807D43B49). Consequently, many productions were subsidized by the government through the Council for Encouragement of Music and the Arts (CEMA) - see, for example, this production of [George Bernard Shaw's *Arms and the Man*](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/203523498402?hash=item2f62f221a2:g:nI8AAOSwdLVgj-BV).

Answer (score -1):

According to [terramedia.co.uk](https://www.terramedia.co.uk/reference/statistics/cinema/cinema_ticket_prices_1.htm) the average price of a theater ticket in London in 1940 was 4.37 pence. The site has prices for other years if you need that information.,

Comment: Those are the prices for movie theatres rather than for stage productions.